# Passing parameters to Google Map Matrix API in C# via HttpClient?

Tags: c#, google-maps

I'm trying to passing two parameters include origin and destination value to google map Matrix api and get response like below:

```
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+ origin + "&destinations="+ destination + "&key=";
```

But seem like it's doesn't work, so did have any way to passing data to this api url?

My full code (use the ASP.Net Core MVC 6):

```
var origin = form["origin"];

var destination = form["destination"];

var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+ origin + "&destinations="+ destination + "&key=";

var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
ViewBag.alert = responseString;
return View();
```

Passing data from html form to api and get the response data

Comment: What is the output of `url` variable? You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. We don't know what your form data is.